# Design a Book model with several editions in a database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, database-design, relational-database

I have a textbook model and I'd like to have several editions of the same textbook (allowing each edition to have different title, price, etc) and be able to retrieve all editions for a particular textbook. How would you design this relation?

My idea is to make the first instance of the book the root book and associate all the subsequent book editions with it. And if I were to delete the root book, for example, another arbitrary root should be chosen automatically from existing editions.

I've looked at [Ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) gem, but it looks like an overkill given that my tree will have a maximum depth 1. Again, I'm not even sure the tree structure is the right solution.

Comment: Would the [papertrail gem](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going with a self-referential approach turned out to be the easiest path. The way I designed it is the first edition added to the database is the root, and all subsequent editions reference it through a `parent_id` attribute. A number of validations then ensure the integrity of such structure (e.g. there can only be one root for a set of editions, deleting the root book automatically picks another root from existing book editions, etc).

Answer (score 4):

In the real world, books are messy.

I'm not sure I've ever seen multiple editions of one book that had different titles, but I guess there's no law against that. If that can really happen, then we probably need to think along the lines of a set of editions being an arbitrary collection of titles.

Let's say we start with this. Imagine that the titles might be different for different editions, although they aren't for this actual book. (Larson's *Calculus* and Spivak's *Calculus*.)

```
Title      ISBN          Price     Edition
--
Calculus   128505709-0   $235.34   10
Calculus   128509108-6   $ 86.50   10
Calculus   054716702-4   $290.65    9
Calculus   061850298-X   $ 67.96    8
Calculus   039586974-9   $ 56.99    6
Calculus   091409891-8   $ 80.75    4
```

We can't select a set of editions by title, because we're letting titles vary among editions, and because the same title can be written by different authors. (The first five above are Larson's *Calculus*; the last one is Spivak's *Calculus*, a completely different textbook.) One edition can be published by different publishers, in which case the title, authors (not shown), and edition would be the same, and the ISBN would be different. (Often, a title's hardback and paperback are published by different publishers.)

All that means the we need another table.

```
Edition name        ISBN
--
Larson's Calculus   128505709-0
Larson's Calculus   128509108-6
Larson's Calculus   054716702-4
Larson's Calculus   061850298-X
Larson's Calculus   039586974-9
Spivak's Calculus   091409891-8
```

On the one hand, it seems clear that this is really all we need to get all the information about a set of editions. Just join on ISBN. In Rails, of course, you'll probably be using id numbers throughout.

The edition name *could* be a title, but we're letting titles vary among editions of one book. So picking a title might cause more problems than it solves.

So I don't think you need another gem to handle this. Just one more model and the right associations.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably set up a simple `has_many` / `belongs_to` association for this:

```
#app/models/book.rb
Class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :editions
end

#app/models/edition.rb
Class Edition < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :book
end
```

This will give you the schemas:

```
#books
id | title | author | created_at | updated_at

#editions
id | book_id | ISBN | price | created_at | updated_at
```

This will allow you to save `@book` with a particular `title` / `author`, and then associate as many `editions` to that book as you want.